# View showing ONLY taxonomy children terms and NO parents

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've managed to got my view working but my worry is that this method is not dynamic.

**What I want to achieve?**
To have a list of articles tagged with terms that are one level deep (children) but not their parent terms.

E.g.: assuming a taxonomy looks like this:

```
A 
  A1
  A2
B
  B1
  B2
```

I want to be able to go to the URL **mysite.com/A/A1** or **mysite.com/B/B2** and retrieve a list of articles with ONLY content tagged with A1 or B2 (in this example)

For that I added a filter and manually selected the parent terms I don't want to list:

[image]

Is there a better solution to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: try taxonomy term with depth

Answer (score 3):

Super simple but impossible to guess solution :

With a normal filter set the "Parent term" filter not equal to "0".

This will filter parents

Answer (score 1):

In your view:

Contextual filters

Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

```
 Depth: 1
 When the filter value is NOT available :
   Type : Taxonomy Term Id from url
   & Select Load default filter from term page
```

Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

Hope this will help you to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

From Contextual filters select:

Content: Has taxonomy term ID and select checkbox Provide default value "taxonomy term id from url" and select checkbox " Load default filter from term page"

and In Relationship:

Relationships
Content: Taxonomy terms on node and select checkbox REquire this relationship.

I hope this will work you.

Comment: Haven't tried this solution. The one above did the job. Thanks!